# Performance of string search

Tags: java, string, servlets

I have a Servlet that needs to process just 1 XML element in an Http response document that is about 2 MB in size and return what ever that is within the element to the client. Currently I am doing this

```
    if (response.indexOf("<?xml") != -1
                && response.indexOf("</Data>") != -1) {
            return response.substring(response.indexOf("<?xml"),
                    response.indexOf("</Data>") + 7);
```

Just wondering if this is the most efficient way of searching for the tags or are there any better approaches available.

Comment: Try with regex, that would be a better approach in this case.

Comment: This is fine but Why not use some Xml Parsing library out there?

Comment: You are not processing the xml, I mean the individual xml elements, hence parser may not be required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that you would be able to speed up the algorithm by much, because the only "false starts" that `IndexOf` would find along the way to `</Data>` would be the closing tags, while `<?xml` is found very close to the beginning of file.

One way to speed up your code is avoid calling `IndexOf` multiple times:

```
int idxXml = response.indexOf("<?xml");
int idxData = response.indexOf("</Data>");
if (idxXml != -1 && idxData != -1) {
    return response.substring(idxXml, idxData+7);
}
```

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Thanks! I've been doing too much C# lately :)